live-build error: cp: cannot stat 'chroot/boot/vmlinuz-*': No such file or directory
I am using live-build to create custom live debian. I started on a fresh Debian Bookworm installation and followed live-build docs.
lb config
sudo lb build

I had some errors for firmware-linux package, but I solved it by adding non-free to apt repos. Thus, this is my sources.list file now:
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm main non-free-firmware non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm main non-free-firmware non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security main non-free-firmware non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security main non-free-firmware non-free

# bookworm-updates, to get updates before a point release is made;
# see https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch02.en.html#_updates_and_backports
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm-updates main non-free-firmware non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm-updates main non-free-firmware non-free

# This system was installed using small removable media
# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
# entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
# For information about how to configure apt package sources,
# see the sources.list(5) manual.

After running build, I get following error:
P: Begin install linux-image...
cp: cannot stat 'chroot/boot/vmlinuz-*': No such file or directory
E: An unexpected failure occurred, exiting...
P: Begin unmounting filesystems...
P: Saving caches...
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done


So, it definitely had something to do with archive areas. So, during configuration, I just needed to pass --archive-area flag with non-free area.
lb config --archive-areas "main contrib non-free"

It took me some time, but least likely thing was causing a problem.

Super useful answer, the only one I could find. Note that you will probably ALSO have to do a lb clean --purge or just nuke everything in your working directly (including the hidden .build folder) to make it regenerate everything correctly.
